# Odd Perfect Numbers attempt

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers

Suppose you have some positive, odd, composite integer $n$. Let 
$$
D = d_1 + d_2 +d_3+...+d_{j-1}
$$

where $d_i$ is some divisor of $n$ and $j$ is an odd number corresponding to the number of proper divisors of $n$. $d_j$ is the last proper divisor of $n$. Assuming that $D \gt \frac{n}{2}$ holds, is there some way to prove that
$$
\frac{D}{d_2-1} \neq d_j
$$

for any $n$ that satisfies the aformentioned constraints? I know that $D$ is always even, $d_2$ is always prime and is at least $3$. I am only concerned about when the quotient is odd which seems to be much rarer than when it is even.

For example: if $n=2205$, then $D=1506$ and $d_2-1=2$. $$\frac{D}{d_2-1}=753\neq d_j = 735$$

Comment: How can we choose $n$ to be a number such that $D>n/2$, if we need to fix $n$ beforehand with $d_i\mid n$ and $D=d_1+\cdots +d_{j-1}$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to word it otherwise. $D$ relies on the divisors on $n$. If you choose an $n$ where $D\lt\frac{n}{2}$, this formula is trivially true because $d_j$ cannot be greater than $\frac{n}{2}$.

Comment: You could say in the $4$-th line: assume that $D>n/2$ holds and ...Does it follow that $D/(d_2-1)\neq d_j$ ? Give a *small* example of such an $n$, fulfilling all assumtions.

Comment: Thank you for that, I adjusted the wording of my question. 2205 is actually the smallest $n$ that fulfills these requirements.

Comment: Since $d_2d_j=n$, you are trying to prove that there is no odd $n$ such that $n=d_1+d_2+\cdots +d_{j-1}+d_j$. In other words, you are trying to prove that there is no odd [perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number).

Comment: You are correct, in order for $n$ to be perfect, the assumptions I've placed on $D$ must hold and specifically, $n-D=d_j$. Is there some way to factor $D$ and $d_2-1$ to prove this? This is sort of a curiosity for me.

Comment: @aesguitar: Is it necessarily true that
$$d_1 < d_2 < d_3 < \ldots < d_{j-1} < d_j?$$

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, just some comments that are too long to fit in the appropriate section.  In what follows, I shall be assuming that
$$d_1 < d_2 < d_3 < \ldots < d_{j-1} < d_j$$
holds.

---

Suppose that $n$ is an *odd perfect number*.  Euler proved that a *hypothetical odd perfect number* must have the form
$$n = p^k m^2$$
where $p$ is the *special/Eulerian prime* satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

So, as you can see, your problem essentially reduces to determining factors of $m$, which is known to be **composite** (in fact, Nielsen has shown that $\omega(m) \geq 9$).  Alas, even with modern computer technology and innovations in factor/sigma-chain methods, no factor chain has terminated that produces a proof for divisibility by a (certain) prime (say, less than $105$).

---

Alternatively, let $s(n)=\sigma(n)-n$ denote the *aliquot sum* (or *sum of proper divisors*) of $n$.  As before, $n$ has the form $n = p^k m^2$.
Then we obtain
$$D + d_j = s(n) = n$$
$$D + d_j = \sigma(p^k)\sigma(m^2) - p^k m^2,$$
where $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.

Once more, you see the paramount importance of determining factors of the component $m$.